# Disable mouse right click and don't change cursor position In Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, mouse

I want to disable mouse right click and don't change cursor position In Javascript. Here is my code example:

```
<input id="PhoneNumber" style="width: 160px;" />

$('#PhoneNumber').mousedown(function (e) {
    if (event.which > 1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        //Do some work
    }
});
```

But This doesn't work. When i am clicking with right mouse button, it changes caret position.

[UPDATED]
Works on chrome. Doesn't working on IE

Comment: Works on chrome. Doesn't working on IE

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the mouseup event also:

```
$('#PhoneNumber').on('mousedown mouseup', function (e) {
        if (event.which > 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            //Do some work
        }
    });
```

Comment: @ArmenMkrtchyan Which version of IE?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the contextmenu event and return false:

```
    $('#PhoneNumber').on("contextmenu", function(e) {
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contextmenu`:

```
$('#PhoneNumber').contextmenu(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dAXJ2/19/)**

Comment: in that demo the cursor changed it's position

Comment: @ArmenMkrtchyan : i dont think you can do that. thats default behaviour of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#PhoneNumber').bind("cut copy paste contextmenu", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var pos = ($(this).getCursorPosition());
            var index = $('#PhoneNumber').val().length;
            if (index < 5) {
                index = 5;
            }
            $(this).caretTo(index);
        });

        $('#PhoneNumber').click(function () {
            var pos = ($(this).getCursorPosition());
            var index = $('#PhoneNumber').val().length;
            if (index < 5) {
                index = 5;
            }
            $(this).caretTo(index);
        });

        $('#PhoneNumber').on('mousedown mouseup', function (e) {
            if(event.which!=1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = false;
            }
        });
```